# Minute time series in R. How to insert missing values in order to have the same steps in time?

Tags: r, datetime, bloomberg

I have a dataset where column 1 is date-time and column 2 is the price at a specific point in time. This data is downloaded to Excel with bloomberg excel add-in. Then I used read_excel function to import this file to R.

[This is how the data looks like in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gRqz.png)

Question: the data is supposed to be with 1 min intervals, but it is not always the case. Sometimes the time in the next row is more than 1 min later. So, how can I insert extra rows for the missing minutes? So, for each date I would like to have the following sequence:

08:00

08:01

08:02

...

16:58

16:59

17:00

For these points in time, I would like keep the price from the dataset. If the price is not there, it should add missing. For example if we have:

...

12:31 100

12:32 102

12:35 101

...

then I would like to have:

...

12:31 100

12:32 102

12:33 missing

12:34 missing

12:35 101

...

what is the easiest way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: The `padr` package is one straightforward way to add missing time observations.

Comment: you could create a sequence of minutes, and join the data needed on these minuets based on timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an xts with the prices you have and merge it with a sequence that has a higher frequency (e.g. every minute).

```
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

prices <- 100 + rnorm(16)
timeindex <- seq(ymd_hm('2020-05-28 08:45'),
                 ymd_hm('2020-05-28 09:15'),
                 by = '2 mins')

prices_xts <- xts(prices, order.by = timeindex)

> head(prices_xts)
                         [,1]
2020-05-28 08:45:00  99.43952
2020-05-28 08:47:00  99.76982
2020-05-28 08:49:00 101.55871
2020-05-28 08:51:00 100.07051
2020-05-28 08:53:00 100.12929
2020-05-28 08:55:00 101.71506

timeindex2 <- seq(ymd_hm('2020-05-28 08:45'),
                  ymd_hm('2020-05-28 09:15'),
                  by = '1 mins')

prices_with_gaps_xts <- merge.xts(prices_xts,
                                  timeindex2)

> head(prices_with_gaps_xts)
                    prices_xts
2020-05-28 08:45:00   99.43952
2020-05-28 08:46:00         NA
2020-05-28 08:47:00   99.76982
2020-05-28 08:48:00         NA
2020-05-28 08:49:00  101.55871
2020-05-28 08:50:00         NA
```